# How to initialize AVAudioPlayer in Swift

Tags: swift, initialization, avaudioplayer

I have this file and want to use this file in another class, but this does not work. I assume that this is because I have not initialized the `AVAudioPlayer` in this file, so I tackled with this, but a message appeared, saying `"Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"` My implementation was unsuccessful. I have no idea how to deal with this. Could you point out what is wrong with the initialization and provide me with some code that works. Thanks in advance.

```
class SoundManager: AVAudioPlayer {
var _Sound: AVAudioPlayer!

override init() {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("rain", withExtension: "wav")
    super.init(contentsOfURL: url!)
}

func playSound() {


    if (url == nil) {
        print("Could not find the file \(_Sound)")
    }

    do {
        _Sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil)

    }
    catch let error as NSError { print(error.debugDescription)

    }
    if _Sound == nil {
        print("Could not create audio player")
    }
    _Sound.prepareToPlay()
    _Sound.numberOfLoops = -1
    _Sound.play()
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use this way init you manager, It does not have to be subclass of AVAudioPlayer.

```
class SoundManager {
    var _Sound: AVAudioPlayer!
    var url: NSURL?

    /**
     init with file name

     - parameter fileName: fileName

     - returns: SoundManager
     */
    init(fileName: String) {
        url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: "wav")
    }

    func playSound() {
        if (url == nil) {
            print("Could not find the file \(_Sound)")
        }

        do {
            _Sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil)

        }
        catch let error as NSError { print(error.debugDescription)

        }
        if _Sound == nil {
            print("Could not create audio player")
        }
        _Sound.prepareToPlay()
        _Sound.numberOfLoops = -1
        _Sound.play()
    }
}
```

Use

`let manager = SoundManager(fileName: "hello")
manager.playSound()`

Comment: Worked!! I thought implementing AVAuiodPlayer as a subclass was necessary. I am curious about In what situation, should I use it then?

Comment: @ryohei  When you want to use this manager `as` AVAudioPlayer, then use subclass. It will inihrit the property and functions of superclass. When it comes to manager class, I prefer to create class without subclass, and give it an instance of AVAudioPlayer like you did at line `var _Sound: AVAudioPlayer!`. Don't forget to mark my answer as useful~~

Comment: Oh, I see. I am happy to solve this! Thanks for your answer :)